# What is the most powerful backup method on ubuntu?

Tags: backup, ubuntu-16.04

I use rsync with daily and weekly backup on ubuntu.
Then for monthly backup, I use tar command to backup it.
Has Anybody monthly backup method other than tar command?
I mean if I use tar command with a lot of data, it takes too long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two other solutions:

1. make an image of partitions that contain the system, you may want to compress it what is also possible while backing up (on-the-fly)
2. TimeShift which has been introduced into last version of Linux Mint (19)

Seems that rsync is very good solution and you shouldn't change it, those above two solutions are for special usage (need more info about system and application of it).

Comment: Seconded. I used to run Clonezilla to image the system every two weeks.

Comment: Aah - to compress the image of partition you may want to zero all the free space with some script to make the compressed image smaller in size. Forgot to mention.